# Pyserial how to send ascii character

Tags: python, send, stm32, pyserial

I use sliders on my project. These change and i send my stm32 side and drive motors. My stm32 sides take angle type ascii, but pyserial side send integer, i want send 54 degres on my slider value and pyserial send 90's ascii type 6 how can i do that ?

```
    def servoGripperFunc(self):
        print "gripper buttonuna basildi"



    def sliderMoveFunc(self):
        print "Slider 1:"
        print self.horizontalSlider.value()
        ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0')
        print(ser.name)
        if ser.isOpen():
            print(ser.name + ' is open')
        size=(self.horizontalSlider.value())
        dgr=ord(size)
        ser.write(str(dgr))
        time.sleep(1)



        #print "Slider 2:"
        #print self.horizontalSlider_2.value()
        #print "Slider 3:"
        #print self.horizontalSlider_3.value()
        #print "Slider 4:"
        #print self.horizontalSlider_4.value()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtGui.QApplication([])

    myWindow = MyWindowClass()
    myWindow.setWindowTitle("PyServo for " +
                            platform.system() + " v." + software_version)
    myWindow.setVisible(True)

    myWindow.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: myWindow.servoGripperFunc())
    myWindow.horizontalSlider.sliderMoved.connect(lambda: myWindow.sliderMoveFunc())
    myWindow.horizontalSlider_2.sliderMoved.connect(lambda: myWindow.sliderMoveFunc())
    myWindow.horizontalSlider_3.sliderMoved.connect(lambda: myWindow.sliderMoveFunc())
    myWindow.horizontalSlider_4.sliderMoved.connect(lambda: myWindow.sliderMoveFunc())


    # Start the window centered in screen
    screenGeometry = app.desktop().screenGeometry()
    x = (screenGeometry.width() - myWindow.width()) / 2
    y = (screenGeometry.height() - myWindow.height()) / 2
    myWindow.move(x, y)

    app_exec_code = app.exec_()

    app.quit()
```

Comment: which format do you want to sen over serial? one byte will contain value in degrees? or how?

Comment: hexadecimal value